# GTA 5 disc on PS4

Tags: ps4, grand-theft-auto-v

Can you play GTA 5 disc on PS4 online? I know you need to have PS+ if you're buying game from PSN to play it but I want to buy disc so I don't have to get PS+.Is it possible?

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know you need to have PS+ if you're buying game from PSN to play it

No, this is wrong. You can purchase games on PSN and play them without PS Plus.

This handy chart (from 2015) found on [Game Fanatics](https://thegamefanatics.com/playstation-plus-increasing-price/) illustrates what PS Plus offers:

[image: Playstation Plus chart]

|  | PS4 | PS3 | PS Vita |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Online Multiplayer | ➕ Plus | FREE | FREE |
| Instant Game Collection | ➕ Plus | ➕ Plus | ➕ Plus |
| Exclusive Discounts | ➕ Plus | ➕ Plus | ➕ Plus |
| Online Game Saves | ➕ Plus | ➕ Plus | ➕ Plus |
| Automatic System Updates | FREE | FREE | FREE |
| Exclusive Betas | ➕ Plus | ➕ Plus | ➕ Plus |
| Full Game Trials | Coming Soon to Plus | ➕ Plus | ❌ n/a |
| Non-Game Apps | FREE | FREE | FREE |

Not much has changed since 2015. The most important changes being the release of the PS5, and [the discontinuation of Instant Game Collection for PS3 and PS Vita in 2018](https://gameluster.com/no-more-free-ps-plus-games-for-ps3-and-ps-vita/).

As you can see, you will need PS Plus to play online multiplayer games on PS4. It doesn't matter if you bought the game on PSN or as a disc.

There exist a few exceptions to that rule, though, according to the [official Playstation site](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/ps-plus/#accordion-section-5):

> Do I need PlayStation Plus to play Fortnite?
>
> No – Fortnite and other free-to-play games such as Apex Legends, World of Tanks and Spellbreak are free to download and play online.

Since GTA 5 is not a free-to-play game, PS Plus is necessary in order to play online.